# pybind11: multi-thread crash

Tags: c++, python-3.x, pybind11

I have a list of item called `L`, and a sophisticated python function called `func`; the normal way is to use python-loop like:

```py
out = [func(item) for item in L]
```

But it's single-thread, so I want to implement a function in c++, and bind with pybind11:

For cpp:

```
m.def("test_func_iter", [](const py::object &func, const py::sequence &iter) {
        auto n = len(iter);
        py::list l(n);
        unsigned int k = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
        
        std::thread threads[k];

        auto stride = n / k;

        // [0, n//k), [n//k, ...), [...,n)
        for (unsigned int w = 0; w < k; ++w) {
            if (w < k - 1) {
                threads[w] = std::thread([&l, &func, &iter](size_t start, size_t end) {
                    for (size_t i = start; i < end; ++i) {
                        std::cout << "h: "<< i << std::endl;
                        l[i] = func(iter[i]);
                    }
                }, w * stride, (w + 1) * stride);
            } else {
                threads[w] = std::thread([&l, &func, &iter](size_t start, size_t end) {
                    for (size_t i = start; i < end; ++i) {
                        std::cout << "h: "<< i << std::endl;
                        l[i] = func(iter[i]);
                    }
                }, w * stride, n);
            }
        }
        std::cout << "Done spawning threads! Now wait for them to finish.\n";
        for (auto& t: threads) {
            t.join();
        }

        std::cout << "end" << std::endl;
       
        return py::type::of(iter)(l);
```

And when I invoke the corresponding bind function in python, like:

```py
def func(i):
    # just simplify the actual logic, a sophisticated function that is hard to re-write totally in c++
    print(i, i == 0)
    return int(gmpy2.mpz(i) + 100)


b = test_func_iter(func, list(range(100)))
print(b)
```

And I get the output and error like:

```bash
h: h: Done spawning threads! Now wait for them to finish.
050

0 True

进程已结束，退出代码为 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

I have done some tries:

1. **Not use thread** : everything is OK in python
2. **Use thread & k=1**: just use one single thread, everything is OK in python
3. **Use thread & k>=2**: crash.

BTW, I use Mac M1 laptop, and version of clang is 12.05 ;

I am new to c++, and guess the reason may be the use of **thread**, but can not find some suggestions in google, can anybody give some hints?(Or some suggestions about the origin problem: **elegant way for multi-thread support with pybind11**) Thanks!

Comment: You can't run Python code in more than one thread at a time. Full stop, end of story. This is just how Python is designed.

Comment: You can't use C++ threads to run Python code, but you **can** run C++ code in Python threads. If you can rewrite the heavy parts of your code in C++ and wrap them to Python you could release the GIL when calling the C++ code and achieve speedups. Releasing the GIL is very easy with pybind11: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/misc.html#global-interpreter-lock-gil

Comment: Thank you. I know how to release gil,  but if rewrite is necessary, maybe directly do multi-thread in c++ is more efficiently? I do not see any example of releasing gil in function and use multi-thread in Python......

Comment: Personally I've had pretty good results with this approach, but obviously writing everything in c++ will always be faster as Amdahl's law applies. Can't tell you what will be easier in your case :)